# Modal conflict between layout css and view css using AdminLTE and yii2FullCalendar

Tags: css, yii2, modal-dialog, fullcalendar, adminlte

Im using Admin LTE 3.0 and yii2fullcalendar v3.9.0

I have set a sidebar in my main layout with Admin LTE.
Now I want to set yii2fullcalendar with a script that gets the date I click in the calendar, and shows a modal form to create events with the date already set.

The problem is the modal doesn’t show because adminlte.css is causing a malfunction.
See image below

[image: Modal doesn't show]

Here’s the code

CalendarioAsset.php

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class CalendarioAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/calendario/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/calendario/createEvent.js',
        'js/jquery.min.js'

    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',          
    ];
}
```

DashboardAsset.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * Main application asset bundle.
 *
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class DashboardAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        'css/all.min.css',
        'css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css',
        'css/adminlte.css',
        'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700'


    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/jquery.min.js',
        'js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
        'js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js',
        'js/adminlte.js',
        'js/demo.js',
        'js/jquery.mousewheel.js',
        'js/raphael.min.js',
        'js/jquery.mapael.min.js',
        'js/usa_states.min.js',
        'js/Chart.min.js',
        'js/dashboard2.js'

    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

view index.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
use app\assets\CalendarioAsset;
use yii\web\JsExpression;

CalendarioAsset::register($this);

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\CalendarioSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Calendario de Reuniones';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="calendario-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Ver lista', ['lista'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        <?= Html::a('Crear Reunión', ['create_lista'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <?php 
            Modal::begin([
                'header' => '<h3>Crear Evento</h3>',
                'id'=>'create',
                'size'=>'modal-lg',
            ]);

            echo "<div id='modalCreate'></div>";
            Modal::end();
        ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <?php 
            Modal::begin([
                'header' => '<h3>Información del evento</h3>',
                'id'=>'view',
                'size'=>'modal-lg',
            ]);

            echo "<div id='modalView'></div>";
            Modal::end();
        ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <?php
            Modal::begin([
                'header' => '<h3>Actualizar evento</h3>',
                'id' => 'update',
                'size' => 'modal-lg'
            ]);
            echo "<div id='modalUpdate'></div>";
            Modal::end();
        ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <?php 
            $JsEventClick = 'function(event) {
                $.get("index.php?r=calendario/view", {"id": event.id}, function(data){
                    $("#view").modal("show")
                           .find("#modalView")
                           .html(data);
               });            
            }'
        ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <?php
            $JsEventDrop = 'function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
                    var event_data = {
                        id: event.id,
                        fecha_inicio: $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "YYYY-MM-DD"),
                        hora_inicio: $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "HH:mm"),
                        hora_termino: $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "HH:mm"),
                        fecha_termino: $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "YYYY-MM-DD"),
                    };
                    if (!confirm("¿Está seguro que desea modificar la fecha y/o hora?")) {
                        revertFunc();
                    }
                    else {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "index.php?r=calendario/update-drop" + "&id=" + event_data.id 
                            + "&fecha_inicio=" + event_data.fecha_inicio + "&hora_inicio=" + event_data.hora_inicio 
                            + "&hora_termino=" + event_data.hora_termino + "&fecha_termino=" + event_data.fecha_termino,
                            success: function(json) {
                                alert("Fecha y/o hora modificada correctamente");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }'
        ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <?php
            $JsEventResize = 'function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
                    var event_data = {
                        id: event.id,
                        hora_inicio: $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "HH:mm"),
                        hora_termino: $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "HH:mm"),
                    };
                    if (!confirm("¿Está seguro que desea modificar la hora?")) {
                        revertFunc();
                    }
                    else {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "index.php?r=calendario/update-resize" + "&id=" + event_data.id 
                            + "&hora_inicio=" + event_data.hora_inicio + "&hora_termino=" + event_data.hora_termino,
                            success: function(json) {
                                alert("Hora modificada correctamente");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }'
        ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <?php
            $JsEventRender = 'function(event, element){
                element.popover({
                    title: "Descripción",
                    animation:true,
                    delay: 300,
                    placement: "top",
                    content: event.description,
                    trigger: "hover",
                    container: "body",
                });
            }'
        ?>
    </p>

    <p>
        <?= yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget([
            'events' => $events,
            'id' => 'calendario',
            'options' => [
                      'lang' => 'es',
                    ],
            'clientOptions' => [
                    'selectable' => false,
                    'editable' => true,
                    'droppable' => true,
                    'header' => [
                        'left' => 'prev,next,today',
                        'center' => 'title',
                        'right' => 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listDay',
                        ],
                'minTime' => '08:00',
                'maxTime' => '21:00',
                'height' => 'auto',
                'snapDuration' => '00:05:00',
                'eventRender' => new JsExpression($JsEventRender),
                'eventClick' => new JsExpression($JsEventClick),
                'eventDrop' => new JsExpression($JsEventDrop),
                'eventResize' => new JsExpression($JsEventResize),
                    ],
            ]);
        ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

That’s the thing, it doesn’t break, it just doesn’t show the modal. The main window fades but the modal doesn’t appear.

calendario/site.css

```
.modal {
    overflow-y: scroll!important;
    overflow-x: visible;
    display: block;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.modal-header {
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    padding-bottom: 0px;    
}

.modal-body {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.modal-open {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: scroll!important;
}

.modal-content{
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

adminlte.css

```
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50px);
  transform: translate(0, -50px);
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    transition: none;
  }
}

.modal.show .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}

.modal-dialog-scrollable {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  max-height: calc(100% - 1rem);
}

.modal-dialog-scrollable .modal-content {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 1rem);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-dialog-scrollable .modal-header,
.modal-dialog-scrollable .modal-footer {
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.modal-dialog-scrollable .modal-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal-dialog-centered {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: calc(100% - 1rem);
}

.modal-dialog-centered::before {
  display: block;
  height: calc(100vh - 1rem);
  content: "";
}

.modal-dialog-centered.modal-dialog-scrollable {
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal-dialog-centered.modal-dialog-scrollable .modal-content {
  max-height: none;
}

.modal-dialog-centered.modal-dialog-scrollable::before {
  content: none;
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  outline: 0;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
}

.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-backdrop.show {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.modal-header {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9ecef;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.modal-header .close, .modal-header .mailbox-attachment-close {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: -1rem -1rem -1rem auto;
}

.modal-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.modal-body {
  position: relative;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.modal-footer {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #e9ecef;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.modal-footer > :not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: .25rem;
}

.modal-footer > :not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: .25rem;
}

.modal-scrollbar-measure {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 1.75rem auto;
  }
  .modal-dialog-scrollable {
    max-height: calc(100% - 3.5rem);
  }
  .modal-dialog-scrollable .modal-content {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
  }
  .modal-dialog-centered {
    min-height: calc(100% - 3.5rem);
  }
  .modal-dialog-centered::before {
    height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
  }
  .modal-content {
    box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  .modal-sm {
    max-width: 300px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .modal-lg,
  .modal-xl {
    max-width: 800px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .modal-xl {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}
```

I don't know how to edit adminlte.css to show the calendar's modal

Comment: what is unclear is where is your modal window activated from ? i just saw the https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/pages/calendar.html and dont see any modal window popup

Comment: Did you include the CSS for bootstrap? I can't see it mentioned

Comment: Modal is activated by createEvent.js when I click a day in the calendar. Yii automatically adds BootstrapAsset in CalendarioAsset, it includes bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

well as for sight there are some conflicts between your js file so if you can provide me with an error console to see what is happening otherwise I've seen in your consol a little bit of red color that means there is some error what I advice delete the assets of admin Lte permanently and try if the model is working

Comment: and try to add bootstrap assets for both CSS and js file

Comment: I've posted same issue in the yii forum, and emuthomi and @softark told me that the modal-content might be hidden. I found out that Admin LTE stops working without adminlte.min.css, that is the css file that conflicts with .modal, .modal-body, .modal-open, and .modal-content. Here's the url https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/modal-doesnt-show-using-admin-lte-v3-0-yii2fullcalendar-v3-9-0/129269/7 I've posted a screenshot with the elements properties of the devtools in chrome.

Comment: what you can do try to do some ajax and put your calendar on another layout with its assets I think that will help for me I don't use the full calendar of Philippe I've searched for a solution on PHP and I've changed it quite bit to work with on Yii so don't waste your time a lot with those things you don't have many solutions and things to do expect using ajax to renger or to work with another solution hope that i helped you

Comment: @InsaneSkull got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

late reply, but I hope it helps. I had a similar problem, the bootstrap4 modal did not show me the content, I discovered that in my custom css I was using the root :root to declare the color palette variables, if I commented it out (:root), the modal was displayed correctly , because this error I have no idea, maybe someone with more knowledge can explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem using bootstrap4 modal in adminlte3 template. Calling modal break adminlte layout, because yii2 automatically inject 3 bootstrap files (js, css, jquery), makes it confict with adminlte assets. So i have to prevent/disable it using below codes in every view files using modal:

```
Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset'] = false; // Add this to prevent bootstrap4 Modal css file injected
Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapPluginAsset'] = false; // Add this to prevent bootstrap4 Modal js file injected
Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles['yii\web\JqueryAsset'] = false; // Add this to prevent jquery file injected
```

I don’t know it is a best practice or not, but it solved my problem.